# What does the Liferay documentation mean by "without using the indexer"

Tags: indexing, liferay, liferay-6

In the [Liferay documentation](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html#search(long,%20long,%20java.util.List,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Double,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date,%20int,%20java.util.Date,%20int,%20int,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator)), many *LocalServiceUtil classes have `search` methods with the following documentation:

> Returns an ordered range of all the [...] matching the parameters **without using the indexer**, including keyword parameters for [...].

What does the `without using the indexer` part of the sentence mean?

In particular, does it mean that it does not use any database indexes? Does it mean that for instance [JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.search](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html#search(long,%20long,%20java.util.List,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Double,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date,%20int,%20java.util.Date,%20int,%20int,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator)) can be expected to run much slower than the equivalent [JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticles](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleServiceUtil.html#getArticles(long,%20long))? Or is it a different meaning?

Or does this `indexer` refer to the `indexes in the result set` in the same method's documentation, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `indexer` refers to searchengine indexers such as those using Lucene, Solr, Elastic (or similar) implementations.
`search` and `getArticles` operations will query the database - if you do a keyword search your database might not use in (DB) index, because `content` or `title` are not part of an index by default. Therefore, when there is a bigger amount of articles, a keyword searchengine query might lead to a better response time.

Comment: yup, plus: Content and Title aren't even keywords or indexable ad all by the database, as multilingual content might be encoded in XML, all in the same field.